# Is my (SPSS) independent t test correct, and how should I intrepret it?

Tags: t-test

I have a sample size of 158 students belonging to IT(N=77) and non-IT disciplines(N=81).

I have carried out the independent sample t-test but I am not sure whether it's correct or not.

Moreover, how do I interpret in my writing that the group differences have impact on other factors.
[image]
[image]

I'd also appreciate if you're able to share a reference paper explaining the values to focus on.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you want to do is check Levene's test to determine which t-statistic is the most accurate. If the test is significant, then the variances of the two groups are not equal and the uncorrected t-statistic assumes that group variance is equal.

Looking at your results, the group variances are not equal for PE, EE, MR, and BI, so for these groups you want to use the "Equal variances not assumed" values, and you would want to make sure to report that. We know that that are not equal by looking at the value under Sig. and noticing that there are some that are lower than the standard level of .05

Looking at your t-tests, you've shown that discipline has a significant effect on the group means for the PE, EE, MR, PP, and BI groups. We know this by looking at the Sig. (2-tailed) column and making note of the values that are lower than the standard level of .05. Anything higher is not statistically different. Next you want to look at the means in order to determine what direction the effect is in.

For

PE: 1 > 2
EE: 1 > 2
MR: 1 > 2
PP: 1 > 2
BI: 1 > 2

So the differences are all in the same direction.

As for reporting the results, by way of example:

Two-tailed, independent t-tests demonstrated that discipline significantly affected group means for PE [t(135.37) = 4.7, p < .001], EE [t(131.96) = 4.4, p < .001], MR [t(149.68) = 5.2, p < .001], PP [t(156) = 4.9, p < .001], and BI [t(148.31), p < .01]. For all groups the mean was greater for discipline 1 than discipline 2.

Most papers on the t-test won't cover the basics that you're looking for, but most introductory textbooks on Statistics will.

Comment: How should Type I error inflation with the multiple tests, including Levene's (yes, that inflates error too) be taken into account? Does it have an impact here? Also, shouldn't the reporting indicate when equal and unequal variance tests are used? Is the variance across groups in PM really that much more similar than the variance across groups in PR that it justifies different tests?

Comment: Why ever bother using the assumption that variances are equal in a single *t* test? (i.e. not in an ANOVA *post hoc* type setting). When the variances *are* equal in actuality, the form of *t* test assuming difference variances gives the same result as the one assuming equal variances.

Comment: @John - there are better tests for data with unequal variances. I personally wouldn't use a t-test if that were the case. In the reporting you wouldn't just mention it as I have, but you'd also include the F and p of the test as well. You'd have to do extra analysis to determine whether the variances are really that difference, by how much, etc.

Comment: @Alexis - There's not much point, you're right, but the question was phrased in such a way that it seemed to be coming from a student working on an assignment or practice set in a class so I proceeded as such. In that case, what other things you can do when the variance are not equal would be followed up in later lessons.